# Animation assistance with a circle using JavaScript in a Canvas--what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create simple animation to take the moon that I have drawn behind the clouds and allow users to move it across the x axis in the canvas. I have seen where others have done this with rectangles, and I have seen where their code seems basic enough for my inexperience to follow... but I'm struggling a bit with my code.

Every time I put code in that I think will work, it wipes out the canvas... which means I have placement and structural issues... but I'm having trouble figuring out where and how.

Can someone help me figure out how to animate my `drawMoon` so that it will move across the x axis when the left and right arrow keys are used?

***NOTE*** I have tried using event listeners for keydown and keyup, but I'm sure I'm doing it wrong.

Attaching code that has nothing included so that you all have the base code without the animation attempt.

Any help is appreciated.

******UPDATE*** I think I broke it more..... thoughts?***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Howling at the Moon</title>
</head>

<body onload="init();">

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="900">Your browser does not support the canvas tag.</canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    
    var canvas, ctx;
    var moonx = 0;
    var moony = 0;
    var moonAngle = 0;
    var incrementX = 0;

    function init() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeydown, false);
      window.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyup, false);
      drawMonster(260, 260);
      drawMoon(100, 100);
      drawCloud(150, 175);
      requestId = requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);

      function handleKeydown(evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode === 37) {
          incrementX = -1;
        } else if (evt.keyCode === 39) {
          incrementX = 1;
        }
      }

      function handleKeyup(evt) {
        incrementX = 0;
      }

      function animationLoop() {
        context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'
      }
      drawMoon(moonx, moony, moonAngle, "green", "yellow");
      moonx += incrementX;
      requestId = requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
    }

    function drawMonster(x, y) {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(740, 750, 175, 0, Math.PI / 0.5);
      ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.lineWidth = 3;
      ctx.stroke();
      //mouth1
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.fillRect(x + 350, y + 550, 200, 20);
      //mouth2
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.fillRect(x + 375, y + 540, 150, 20);
      //mouth3
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.fillRect(x + 375, y + 560, 150, 20);
      ctx.restore();
      //eyes
      addShadows2();
      ctx.fillStyle = "lightslategrey";
      ctx.fillRect(x + 350, y + 400, 40, 40);
      ctx.fillRect(x + 450, y + 400, 40, 40);
      //pupil
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.fillRect(x + 350, y + 400, 20, 20);
      ctx.fillRect(x + 450, y + 400, 20, 20);
    }
    //moon
    function drawMoon(moonx, moony) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(100, 75, 150, 0, Math.PI / 0.5);
      ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";
      addShadows();
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.lineWidth = 3;
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    //cloud
    function drawCloud(x, y) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, 60, Math.PI * 0.5, Math.PI * 1.5);
      ctx.arc(x + 70, y - 60, 70, Math.PI * 1, Math.PI * 1.85);
      ctx.arc(x + 152, y - 45, 50, Math.PI * 1.37, Math.PI * 1.91);
      ctx.arc(x + 200, y, 60, Math.PI * 1.5, Math.PI * 0.5);
      ctx.moveTo(x + 200, y + 60);
      ctx.lineTo(x, y + 60);
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#797874";
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fillStyle = "lightslategrey";
      ctx.fill();
    }

    function addShadows() {
      ctx.shadowColor = "beige"; // color
      ctx.shadowBlur = 160; // blur level
      ctx.shadowOffsetX = 15; // horizontal offset
      ctx.shadowOffsetY = 15; // vertical offset
    }

    function addShadows2() {
      ctx.shadowColor = "black";
      ctx.shadowBlur = 40;
      ctx.shadowOffsetX = 15;
      ctx.shadowOffsetY = 10;
    }

    function addShadows3() {
      ctx.shadowColor = "beige";
      ctx.shadowBlur = 160;
      ctx.shadowOffsetX = 10;
      ctx.shadowOffsetY = 10;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code currently works at drawing the shapes. Can you share your animation attempt? At least enough to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sure.... see new code added.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Howling at the Moon</title>
</head>

<body onload="init();">

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="900">Your browser does not support the canvas tag.</canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas, ctx;

    function init() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown, false);
      window.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyup, false);
      drawMonster(260, 260);
      drawMoon(100, 100);
      drawCloud(150, 175);

      function handleKeydown(evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode === 37) {
          //left key 
          incrementX = -1;
        } else if (evt.keyCode === 39) {
          // right key
          incrementX = 1;
        }
      }

      function drawMonster(x, y) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(740, 750, 175, 0, Math.PI / .5);
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.stroke();
        //mouth1
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
        ctx.fillRect(x + 350, y + 550, 200, 20);
        //mouth2
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
        ctx.fillRect(x + 375, y + 540, 150, 20);
        //mouth3
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
        ctx.fillRect(x + 375, y + 560, 150, 20);
        ctx.restore();
        //eyes
        addShadows2();
        ctx.fillStyle = 'lightslategrey'
        ctx.fillRect(x + 350, y + 400, 40, 40);
        ctx.fillRect(x + 450, y + 400, 40, 40);
        //pupil
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
        ctx.fillRect(x + 350, y + 400, 20, 20);
        ctx.fillRect(x + 450, y + 400, 20, 20);
      }
      
      function animateMoon()
      {
        ctx.clearArc(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        drawMoon(x,y);
        requestId = requestAnimationFrame(animateMoon);
      }
      
      //moon
      function drawMoon(x, y) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(100, 75, 150, 0, Math.PI / .5);
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";
        addShadows();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.stroke();
      }
      //cloud
      function drawCloud(x, y) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, 60, Math.PI * 0.5, Math.PI * 1.5);
        ctx.arc(x + 70, y - 60, 70, Math.PI * 1, Math.PI * 1.85);
        ctx.arc(x + 152, y - 45, 50, Math.PI * 1.37, Math.PI * 1.91);
        ctx.arc(x + 200, y, 60, Math.PI * 1.5, Math.PI * 0.5);
        ctx.moveTo(x + 200, y + 60);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y + 60);
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#797874";
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightslategrey";
        ctx.fill();
      }

      function addShadows() {
        ctx.shadowColor = "beige"; // color
        ctx.shadowBlur = 160; // blur level
        ctx.shadowOffsetX = 15; // horizontal offset
        ctx.shadowOffsetY = 15; // vertical offset
      }

      function addShadows2() {
        ctx.shadowColor = "black";
        ctx.shadowBlur = 40;
        ctx.shadowOffsetX = 15;
        ctx.shadowOffsetY = 10;
      }

      function addShadows3() {
        ctx.shadowColor = "beige";
        ctx.shadowBlur = 160;
        ctx.shadowOffsetX = 10;
        ctx.shadowOffsetY = 10;
      }

      function start() {
        // Start the animation loop, targets 60 frames/s
        requestId = requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
      }

      function stop() {
        if (requestId) {
          cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
        }
      }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Howling at the Moon</title>
</head>

<body onload="init();">

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="900">Your browser does not support the canvas tag.</canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas, ctx;

    function init() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown, false);
      window.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyup, false);
      drawMonster(260, 260);
      drawMoon(100, 100);
      drawCloud(150, 175);

      function handleKeydown(evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode === 37) {
          //left key 
          incrementX = -1;
        } else if (evt.keyCode === 39) {
          // right key
          incrementX = 1;
        }
      }

      function drawMonster(x, y) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(740, 750, 175, 0, Math.PI / .5);
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.stroke();
        //mouth1
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
        ctx.fillRect(x + 350, y + 550, 200, 20);
        //mouth2
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
        ctx.fillRect(x + 375, y + 540, 150, 20);
        //mouth3
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
        ctx.fillRect(x + 375, y + 560, 150, 20);
        ctx.restore();
        //eyes
        addShadows2();
        ctx.fillStyle = 'lightslategrey'
        ctx.fillRect(x + 350, y + 400, 40, 40);
        ctx.fillRect(x + 450, y + 400, 40, 40);
        //pupil
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
        ctx.fillRect(x + 350, y + 400, 20, 20);
        ctx.fillRect(x + 450, y + 400, 20, 20);
      }

      function animateMoon() {
        ctx.clearArc(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        drawMoon(x, y);
        requestId = requestAnimationFrame(animateMoon);
      }

      //moon
      function drawMoon(x, y) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(100, 75, 150, 0, Math.PI / .5);
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";
        addShadows();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.stroke();
      }
      //cloud
      function drawCloud(x, y) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, 60, Math.PI * 0.5, Math.PI * 1.5);
        ctx.arc(x + 70, y - 60, 70, Math.PI * 1, Math.PI * 1.85);
        ctx.arc(x + 152, y - 45, 50, Math.PI * 1.37, Math.PI * 1.91);
        ctx.arc(x + 200, y, 60, Math.PI * 1.5, Math.PI * 0.5);
        ctx.moveTo(x + 200, y + 60);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y + 60);
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#797874";
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightslategrey";
        ctx.fill();
      }

      function addShadows() {
        ctx.shadowColor = "beige"; // color
        ctx.shadowBlur = 160; // blur level
        ctx.shadowOffsetX = 15; // horizontal offset
        ctx.shadowOffsetY = 15; // vertical offset
      }

      function addShadows2() {
        ctx.shadowColor = "black";
        ctx.shadowBlur = 40;
        ctx.shadowOffsetX = 15;
        ctx.shadowOffsetY = 10;
      }

      function addShadows3() {
        ctx.shadowColor = "beige";
        ctx.shadowBlur = 160;
        ctx.shadowOffsetX = 10;
        ctx.shadowOffsetY = 10;
      }

      function start() {
        // Start the animation loop, targets 60 frames/s
        requestId = requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
      }

      function stop() {
        if (requestId) {
          cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
        }
      }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It would be best to **Edit** your original post with this animation attempt. Either way, you need to add variables which track values such as x and y values of objects you want to move (`moonX`, `moonY`) so that when a button is pressed, it adjusts those values accordingly. Then make sure to use those variables as the x and y when drawing to the canvas.

Comment: Excellent. I will try. Ty Phentnil

Comment: Updated OP with added code.... but I still cant seem to get it right.... frustrating. ***Note*** I am a novice at this...

Comment: Thanks again for your wonderful feedback and guidance. I really do appreciate your efforts to help me understand and the excellent write up @phentnil

Answer (score 0):

There were several issues in your code and I'll share the changes I made to get the animation to work.

### Errors

In your `animationLoop`, you referenced a variable named `context` which I believe you meant to reference `ctx` instead.

```js
  context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'
```

I can't say I've used this property of the [`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation), but I didn't notice any positive effects it produced for your code and the resulting animation. I first changed it to `ctx.globalCompositeOperation` and eventually removed it.

Another error was that you were declaring `ctx` and `canvas` in your `init` function even though you had variables declared outside the function. I opted to remove the declaration and just make it an assignment instead:

```js
  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

With these changes, the initial errors were resolved.

### Issues

In `init` the shapes are drawn on the canvas and we have two identical lines using `requestAnimationFrame`:

```js
  requestId = requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
  drawMoon(moonx, moony, moonAngle, "green", "yellow");
  moonx += incrementX;
  requestId = requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
```

I removed the first one (also removing the `requestId` assignment as it didn't seem necessary). Then, in order for the `animationLoop` to continue to animate, we need to call `requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop)` inside of the `animationLoop` function.

```js
function animationLoop() {
  // ...
  requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
}
```

Then, in order to actually draw the shapes in each call of `animationLoop`, I moved the `draw<shape>` function calls inside of `animationLoop`. Also, we want to clear the canvas each time we draw on it to properly animate our shapes, so we'll need to use [`.clearRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect). Now the `animationLoop` looks like this:

```js
  function animationLoop() {
    moonx += incrementX;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawMonster(260, 260);
    drawCloud(150, 175);
    drawMoon(moonx, moony, moonAngle, "green", "yellow");
    requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
  }
```

But the final reason the moon won't move when we press the left or right arrows is that we're not actually using the `moonx` and `moony` variables when drawing the moon. So, in `drawMoon`, instead of

```js
ctx.arc(100, 75, 150, 0, Math.PI / .5);
```

this should be changed to the following

```js
ctx.arc(moonx, moony, 150, 0, Math.PI / 0.5);
```

I believe I covered all of the major issues with your code to be able to draw all the shapes and move the moon with the left and right arrows. See the full code example below.

```js
var canvas, ctx;
var moonx = 0;
var moony = 0;
var moonAngle = 0;
var incrementX = 0;

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeydown, false);
  window.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyup, false);
  requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);

  function handleKeydown(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode === 37) {
      incrementX = -1;
    } else if (evt.keyCode === 39) {
      incrementX = 1;
    }
  }

  function handleKeyup(evt) {
    incrementX = 0;
  }

  function animationLoop() {
    moonx += incrementX;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawMonster(260, 260);
    drawCloud(150, 175);
    drawMoon(moonx, moony, moonAngle, "green", "yellow");
    requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
  }
}

function drawMonster(x, y) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(740, 750, 175, 0, Math.PI / 0.5);
  ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.stroke();
  //mouth1
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(x + 350, y + 550, 200, 20);
  //mouth2
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(x + 375, y + 540, 150, 20);
  //mouth3
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(x + 375, y + 560, 150, 20);
  ctx.restore();
  //eyes
  addShadows2();
  ctx.fillStyle = "lightslategrey";
  ctx.fillRect(x + 350, y + 400, 40, 40);
  ctx.fillRect(x + 450, y + 400, 40, 40);
  //pupil
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(x + 350, y + 400, 20, 20);
  ctx.fillRect(x + 450, y + 400, 20, 20);
}
//moon
function drawMoon(moonx, moony) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(moonx, moony, 150, 0, Math.PI / 0.5);
  ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";
  addShadows();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.stroke();
}
//cloud
function drawCloud(x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 60, Math.PI * 0.5, Math.PI * 1.5);
  ctx.arc(x + 70, y - 60, 70, Math.PI * 1, Math.PI * 1.85);
  ctx.arc(x + 152, y - 45, 50, Math.PI * 1.37, Math.PI * 1.91);
  ctx.arc(x + 200, y, 60, Math.PI * 1.5, Math.PI * 0.5);
  ctx.moveTo(x + 200, y + 60);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y + 60);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#797874";
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = "lightslategrey";
  ctx.fill();
}

function addShadows() {
  ctx.shadowColor = "beige"; // color
  ctx.shadowBlur = 160; // blur level
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = 15; // horizontal offset
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 15; // vertical offset
}

function addShadows2() {
  ctx.shadowColor = "black";
  ctx.shadowBlur = 40;
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = 15;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 10;
}

function addShadows3() {
  ctx.shadowColor = "beige";
  ctx.shadowBlur = 160;
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = 10;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 10;
}
init();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="900">Your browser does not support the canvas tag.</canvas>
```